# How can I find a city from latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have latitude and longitude, now have to find city name.

I am using geo codes but I am not getting the correct city name.

But city name is not correct.

Is there have any way through which I get the correct city name?

```
$geocode_stats = file_get_contents("maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/…" . "&sensor=true");
$output_deals  = json_decode($geocode_stats);
$city          = $output_deals->results[0]->address_components[1]->short_name;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code

Comment: i used this code:
$geocode_stats = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$long . "&sensor=true");
$output_deals = json_decode($geocode_stats);
$city = $output_deals->results[0]->address_components[1]->short_name;
but sometime i can not get the correct city name

Comment: I've added your code to the question, it's much easier to read that way

Comment: yeah i was trying to add it in my question ,but that was giving me warning msg that your question does not meets our quality standard.

Comment: Hello PHP-guys, this question is also tagged with google-maps, so when you don't understand the question because you don't know about google-maps, that's no problem, but there is no reason to vote for closing. This question is absolutely clear.

Answer (score 3):

You must loop trough all address_components of a result and find the one with the types-property set to an array:

```
[ "locality", "political" ]
```

Example:

```
<?php

$geocode_stats = file_get_contents(/*the url*/); 
$result='no city found';
$output_deals = json_decode($geocode_stats); 
if($output_deals->status=='OK'){
  $address_components=$output_deals->results[0]->address_components;


  for($i=0;$i<count($address_components);++$i){
    if(array("locality", "political")==$address_components[$i]->types){
      $result=$address_components[$i]->short_name;
      break;
    }
  }

} else{
  $result=$status;
}
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: can you give me example of it. ?

Comment: i print $address_conponents but there is no value such as "locality"

Comment: @moinkhan: What's the requested URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$deal_lat=30.469301;
$deal_long=70.969324;
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$deal_lat.','.$deal_long.'&sensor=false');

        $output= json_decode($geocode);
enter code here
    for($j=0;$j<count($output->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
               $cn=array($output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]);
           if(in_array("locality", $cn))
           {
            $city= $output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
           }
            }
            echo $city;
?>
```

Comment: It is simple code if you need to find city name then replace in_array("country", $cn) to in_array("locality", $cn) if you need to find Zip code then replacein_array("country", $cn) to in_array("postal_code", $cn)